# PayPal Hosted Pro - Error Processing Payment (Amasty Checkout - Magento 1.9.1)

Tags: php, paypal, magento-1.9, payment, onestepcheckout

I've recently installed the Amasty One Step Checkout with "PayPal Website Payments Hosted Pro solution" as the payment method. The site uses the RWD theme.

The problem is when a user makes a purchase it goes through fine the first time, if they then try and make another purchase the checkout redirects to the paypal payment page with the message "Error Processing Payment".

https://securepayments.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess?hosted_button_id=HSSS-WN-Oo2-BuTyYdJ8gCT9r3KEidgZENLcmDBwXyemXiHvUnZpNqnzBVFnWDabxqdvi-6gPcA

The strange thing is if I clear the browser cookie labelled "frontend" it then clears the issue and a user can checkout fine again.

Any help would be much appreciated after days of talking with support and getting nowhere.

Thanks in advance everyone,

TythebarnDev

Answer (score 0):

Hosted Button tokens have an expiry time of around 2 hours from PayPal. Theoretically, the token, if active, can be used multiple times to make the payments. However, since HSS tokens represent a unique checkout, it is not advised to make multiple payments. Example: In case the merchant uses an invoice to create a hosted button token, the subsequent payment attempts will result in “Duplicate Payments”.

The specific Error "Error Processing Payment” looks like a case of Expired Hosted Button token.

Also, the “frontend” cookie seems to be something coming from the Checkout(your) site. PayPal does not read the front end cookie. To me it looks like a control mechanism from your end.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's much appreciated. It was technically right in that it was a token issue, but it turned out that it was a conflict between our Amasty One Step Checkout extension and Paypal Pro.

Their support team ended up taking a look and added this line to the code which fixed the issue. The issue was that on a repeated checkout the paypal hosted pro iframe was loading before the order was complete.

app/code/local/Amasty/Scheckout/Helper/Data.php:901

Added this line $update->addUpdate('<remove name="paypal.iframe"/>');.

Thanks for your help.